# Vim + YouCompleteMe + C: a minimal .ycm_extra_conf.py?

Tags: c, vim, clang

I've already got Vim with YouCompleteMe plugin (compiled with semantic support for C-family languages), which I use for Python etc. Now I'd like to try it with C (I've never developed with C before, so I've got a slightly fuzzy idea about some details, like the necessary flags.)

To use YCM's semantic completion features with C, I need to provide it a `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file; the YCM user guide points to YCM's own `.ycm_extra_conf.py` as a reference ([link](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py)).

Would the following (based on the aforesaid `.ycm_extra_conf.py`) produce "a minimal working setup" for C (to which I could then point `g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf`):

The `flags`:

```
flags = [
'-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror',
'-std=c11',
'-x', 'c'
]
```

and `FlagsForFile` function without the `final_flags.remove( '-stdlib=libc++' )` line.

Otherwise the example file would remain as-it-is. I believe that `-isystem` flags are strictly YCM-related, is that correct?

Answer (score 10):

I was searching for this too and seems here we haven't get a good solution. Even this is a very old question I hope this might help someone. The following works for me,

```
import os
import ycm_core

flags = [
  '-Wall',
  '-Wextra',
  '-Werror',
  '-Wno-long-long',
  '-Wno-variadic-macros',
  '-fexceptions',
  '-ferror-limit=10000',
  '-DNDEBUG',
  '-std=c99',
  '-xc',
  '-isystem/usr/include/',
  ]

SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', ]

def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  return {
  'flags': flags,
  'do_cache': True
  }
```

By the way, that long config file by the default bothers me so much. I should give credit for this post, http://cocoaspice.logdown.com/posts/302432-youcompleteme-toss-notes

Comment: If you're using c++, add a 'c++' flag instead of 'c'. Otherwise it will tell you "you can't use throw with exceptions disabled" and other weird errors.

Comment: Where is that flag?

Comment: "-xc" is the flag. for C++, use "-xc++"

Answer (score 3):

Nothing at all is perfectly valid as long as the sources can be compiled by simply `clang++ -c source` (c vs. c++ is decided from extension). YCM happily completes in scratch tests created in random directories for me.

The `-x c` is not needed. If the source has extension `.c` or `.h`, it is assumed to be C and if it has extension `.C`, `.cc`, `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.H`, `.hh`, `.hpp` or `.hxx` it is assumed C++. Only if you have C++ headers with just `.h` you need `-x c++-header`.

Newest clang (4.9) already defaults to c11 and c++11, so you shouldn't need those either.

So you only need any `-I` flags and the warnings are useful.

Answer (score 3):

To give you a working example, here is the configuration I'm using for Arduino projects.

https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py

In the `flags` I've put all the Arduino libraries provided by the IDE and needed to compile my code.

I've also written a little function to find the other libraries in my `/lib` dir that I'm using in my project and to add them automatically to `flags`. It's [line 57](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L57).

It's helpful if you use a lot of libs and don't want to modify your conf file each time.

Without the `-I /path/to/lib/folder` you won't get autocompletion.

Hope this helps :)